# MYSQL count, group by and where clauses

Tags: mysql

this works

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ,transaction_id FROM loans_applicant  GROUP BY transaction_id
```

however i want to do this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ,transaction_id FROM loans_applicant  GROUP BY transaction_id WHERE count > 4
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: Change the `where` clause to a `having` clause.

Comment: THANKS - how do i mark as the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 2):

That condition should go into `HAVING` clause rather like below. Moreover, you have placed the `WHERE` in wrong position; it should come right after `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ,
transaction_id 
FROM loans_applicant  
GROUP BY transaction_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow order as per below-

```
where
group by
having
order by
```

In this way your query will be-

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ,transaction_id 
FROM loans_applicant 
GROUP BY transaction_id
having count > 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things for that. 
**First :** Use `HAVING` clause.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ,transaction_id FROM loans_applicant  GROUP BY transaction_id having count(*) > 4
```

**Second :** Use Sub Query.

```
 SELECT count from (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ,transaction_id FROM loans_applicant  GROUP BY transaction_id) where count > 4
```